# Find pattern using grep and then replace with sed

Tags: sed, grep, rhel

I have the following lines of code

```
        BalancerMember http://server3:82 status=D
        BalancerMember http://server2:80 status=D
```

I want to search for entries with port 82 and then want to wipe out `status=D`. So , it will look like this

```
        BalancerMember http://server3:82
```

Tried this, but this will not work

```
  grep :82 app.conf | sed -i 's/status=D/ /'
  sed: no input files
```

I need the `-i` option with `sed` because I would like to make the change in file .

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can test a full sed solution

```
sed -i '/:82 /s/status=D//' file
```

where

- `/:82 /` select line with 82
- `s/status=D/` replace status by
- `//` nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, this should work

```
awk '/:82 /{print $1,$2; next} {print}' inputfile
```

You can redirect the output of this into another file.

```
awk '/:82 /{print $1,$2; next} {print}' inputfile >> newfile
```

Generally I don't like to make changes to the original data if it can be helped.

Answer (score 0):

based on the given input

```
awk '$2~/:82$/{$NF=""}1' input.txt > output.txt
```